# Surviving Tokugawa Family Members

Tags: japan

Are there any surviving Tokugawa family members nowadays? From my readings, I noticed that [Kikuko Tokugawa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kikuko,_Princess_Takamatsu) (d. 2004) was the last Tokugawa family member, who married Prince Takamatsu.

Answer (score 1):

I did a little research in that obscure source Wikipedia and found the family tree shows a few members surviving today.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokugawa_clan[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokugawa_clan)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoshitomo_Tokugawa[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoshitomo_Tokugawa)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsunenari_Tokugawa[3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsunenari_Tokugawa)

https://www.google.com/search?q=tokugawa+family+today&oq=tokugaa+family&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l5.8638j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8[4](https://www.google.com/search?q=tokugawa%20family%20today&oq=tokugaa%20family&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l5.8638j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

I strongly suspect that the family has many more surviving branches that are not so closely related to the shoguns.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm surprised that Tokugawa clan still have surviving family members despite their nobility status already obsolete.